# Timing Error in C program

Tags: c, timing

Just for fun, I have written a little C program that, in theory, should win the game of Snake.  I am using it to simulate keystrokes and am testing it on one of the Snake game's in Facebook. The problem is, since I am not doing any image processing or attempting to latch on to the Java in the game itself, my completely time based algorithm varies to due several sources of lag, especially when the game page decides to load a new ad.  Is there a way I could get around this with a time based algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: show us what you got, so we know whether it's the code or your algorithm that's buggy

Comment: [Code is king](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the game like, but you are trying to automate interaction with an alien interface. If the interaction can't be buffered (either it can't, or you didn't find/employ a technique to do so).

The best way to do this would be coupling both blocks together, having your AI be invoked when the game is ready for another order. Failing that, there are some ideas you can use:

- Do some basic processing to find if the game reacted to the command, if not, try again.
- If you can wait and repeat, try to time the lags and make the interaction timed, repeating the same command several times.
- Completely avoid the source of lag, e.g. by using some tool to block advertisements, employing firewall rules to block these specific ads, blocking the script that loads ads, and so on. But this would mean ads are outside the java applet -- if they are, you could just run the applet directly without the "container" page.